# What is the difference between EnforceChangePasswordPolicy and ForceChangePasswordNextLogin?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What is the difference in user experience depending on which one (or both) are set to true?

Answer (score 0):

> `-EnforceChangePasswordPolicy`
>   If set to true, force the user to change their password
>
> `-ForceChangePasswordNextLogin`
>   Forces a user to change their password during their next log in.

Source: [Set-AzureADUserPassword](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/blob/master/azureadps-2.0/AzureAD/Set-AzureADUserPassword.md)

If I'm not mistaking...

- The second one means the user will have to change their password **during their next login**.
- The first one means the `ChangePasswordPolicy` is enabled. This either means the user will have to change their password **every `<configurable-amount-of-time>`**, or

  > In Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C, you can enable users who are signed in with a local account to change their password without having to prove their authenticity by email verification.

Taken from [Configure password change using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-change-custom)

Comment: I should have said 'what is the expected difference'. I don't se any - in both cases, I just get 'invalid username pwd' error message when trying to sign in. I am still confused. (note this sis about B2C).

Comment: Note that if you're using the sign-up and sign-in v1 flow and any of the v2 flows, then these handle `ForceChangePasswordNextLogin` being set to `true` with the `Invalid username and password` error. You must use [the sign-in v1 flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions#v1) to prompt the authenticated user to update their current password to a new one.